# How to Forward Declare a Class that Relies on a Variant Definition, Which In Turn Relies on a Templated Class?

Tags: c++

I have a class named `Foo`. I also have a Templated class named `Fum`. `Fum<Foo>` contains a data member of type `Foo`. Furthermore, I have a variant definition `typedef std::variant< Fum<Foo> /* etc.*/ > var_t;`.
`Foo` contains data members of type `var_t`.

As you can see, `var_t` depends on `Fum` and `Foo`, and `Foo` depends on `var_t`. What sequence of declarations can I do to make the following code compile:

*Read comment for error*

### Attempt 1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>   

// Forward Decls
template <typename T>
class Fum;

class Foo;


typedef std::variant< Fum<Foo> /* etc.*/ > var_t;

template<typename T>
class Fum {

private:

    // Error: Incomplete type Foo.

    T value;

public:
    /*
    +++++ Construct T object emplace +++++
    */
    template<typename ... Params>

    Fum<T>(Params&& ... argsOfT)

        :value(std::forward<Params>(argsOfT)...)

    {}

    Fum<T>(Fum<T>&& fumObj)
        :value(std::move(fumObj.value))
    {}

}; // Fum



class Foo {

private:

    var_t val;


public:


    Foo(var_t&& valParam)

        :val(std::move(valParam))

    {}

}; // Foo
```

### Attempt 2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant> 

// Forward Decls
template <typename T>
class Fum; // note: template is declared here
class Foo;


typedef std::variant< Fum<Foo> /* etc.*/ > var_t;


class Foo {

private:

    var_t val;


public:


    Foo(var_t&& valParam)

        :val(std::move(valParam))

    {}

}; // Foo

template<typename T>
class Fum {

private:
    //  note: in instantiation of template class 
    // 'std::__1::variant<Fum<Foo> >' requested here
    T value;

public:
    /*
    +++++ Construct T object emplace +++++
    */
    template<typename ... Params>

    Fum<T>(Params&& ... argsOfT)

        :value(std::forward<Params>(argsOfT)...)

    {}

    Fum<T>(Fum<T>&& fumObj)
        :value(std::move(fumObj.value))
    {}

}; // Fum
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can.

The variant's alternatives must all be complete types, and your `Fum<T>` stores a `T` as a member.

I had a similar problem a few months ago. I have a design like this where one of the alternatives is a `vector<T>`, which is fine because `vector<T>` is complete even when `T` isn't … but I don't believe that's the case for your `Fum<T>`, and it wasn't the case for me when I started experimenting with some other containers.

If `Fum` instead stored some pointer, and dynamically-allocated its `T`, you'd be okay.

Comment: I made the data member in Foo to be a pointer  to var_t instead. So there is no way to do this without dynamic mem alloc?

Comment: @Amjad: Not that I can think of.

Comment: You could use `std::unigue_ptr<var_t>` instead of a raw pointer to maintain RAII and keep the code reasonably simple.  Otherwise be careful to maintain the rule of 5

Answer (score 1):

Not possible as you have a circular definition with no indirection (pointers or references).  Therefor, all the objects directly contain each other, which ends up requiring that

```
sizeof(var_t) > sizeof(Fum<Foo>) >= sizeof(Foo) >= sizeof(var_t)
```

which is impossible.